# Using Polar Coordinates to Calculate Double Integral

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I've encountered a homework problem which has had me a little bit confused, as it doesn't *feel* as though it marries up very closely with the content in my textbook. I guess that what I'd appreciate most is if someone could verify that I have answered this correctly, and potentially clarify any errors that I've made.

Here is the problem statement:

> Let $S$ define the region inside the cardioid $r=1+\sin(\theta)$, above the x-axis. Using polar coordinates, evaluate $\iint_{S}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dA$.

Here's my attempt at the problem:

> Defining $S$ as $S=\{(r,\theta)\ |\ 0\le\theta\le\pi,\ 0\le r\le1+\sin(\theta)\}$,
>
> $\iint_{S}\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dA = \int_0^\pi \! \int_0^{1+\sin(\theta)} \frac{1}{r}r\ dr\ d\theta = \int_0^\pi \! \int_0^{1+\sin(\theta)} 1\ dr\ d\theta=\pi+2.$

Thank you very much!

Comment: looks alright !

Comment: When you just write out function names like that, $\TeX$ interprets that as a juxtaposition of variable names and formats it accordingly. To get the appropriate font and spacing, you can use predefined commands like `\sin`, or, if you need an operator name for which there isn't a predefined command, you can use `\operatorname{name}`.

Comment: @joriki - Thanks! I'm a bit new to this. :-)

Comment: @Lester: There's an edit link underneath the question.